# Convert ReactNative encode to Dart encode

Tags: flutter, decode, encode

I have something like this:

```
const authHeader = "Basic " + btoa(encodeURI(CONSUMER_KEY) + ":" + encodeURI(CONSUMER_SECRET));
```

It's a code from ReactNative. How can i rewrite it to Dart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [base64Encode](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-convert/base64Encode.html) for `btoa` and [encodeComponent](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-core/Uri/encodeComponent.html) for `encodeURI`.